# nginx as smtp proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, smtp, imap, pop3

I was ordered to configure nginx as SMTP proxy. That's all details I have. I've looked though some books and docs and don't see neither any examples of such configuration nor explanations of why this might be useful. Probably, to handle SMTP AUTH through the http server to decrease load, I don't know.

Could someone point me to the sense of this setup? My nginx.conf is default, no changes made, I don't think you will ask me about it. Would someone be kind to share his experience of SMTP proxy configuration?

Comment: You need to know why you need an SMTP proxy. In my personal view there is no need to have one. What is your purpose of having a SMTP proxy? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you're right, after googling and reading docs, I've understood that I need a separate server to proxy emails to, but there is no need for such configuration when you can have let's say Postfix to handle everything. So, consider this question as non-professional and thank you for all answers.