# Nginx configuration as a POP3/SMTP reverse proxy on DMZ

Tags: nginx, smtp, reverse-proxy, pop3, zimbra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nginx as smtp proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/323162/nginx-as-smtp-proxy)

i am here to ask help about how to configure Nginx as a reverse proxy for POP3/SMTP service. We have a Zimbra server offering services as webmail, POP/SMTP, Calendar, etc. The Zimbra server inside the LAN provides all ok.

After that, i configured an Apache2 as a reverse proxy on DMZ to provide WebMail through HTTPs to external clients. It redirects to Zimbra server on LAN. It all worked ok.

The issue i am facing now is how to provide also POP3/SMTP/POP3SSL/SMTPSSL/TLS service to external clients through a reverse proxy. Apache2 doesn't provide this capabilities, and Nginx community doesn't provide any kind of tutorials, wikis or documents where i can approach a solution.

i would be very grateful is somebody could send me some doc or tip.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can redirect you to this link:

[nginx as smtp proxy](https://serverfault.com/questions/323162/nginx-as-smtp-proxy)

Nginx offers a lot of modules for this apparently.

For example: MailCoreModule => http://wiki.nginx.org/MailCoreModule

Hope this helps?

Comment: Hi @Strangler,thanks for your answer. I am aware of this docs on wiki nginx section, but what i was asking was about some config doc where everything is configured at the same time: SMTP, POP3, SSL, TLS, AUTH, etc.